# SystemTap support for user space application

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, systemtap

I want to know how to add support in the systemtap for user space applications. When I am trying to trace any user space program, it is showing that CONFIG_UTRACE not set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps utrace facility is not set up in your kernel.  [Refer here](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/SystemTap_Beginners_Guide/userspace-probing.html) for setting it up and trying again.

Answer (score 0):

Note that linux >3.5 includes a subset of old utrace-related capabilities, so e.g. on x86, process.function probes work directly.